# What is the POST Body to create Multiple Fields in a single Sharepoint REST API call?

Tags: rest, api, http-post, postman, sharepoint-online

I need the POST body for creating multiple fields using a SINGLE Sharepoint REST API call. I'm using Postman, not some web framework.

**Example:**

- URL: `https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/teams/test/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<list name>')/fields`
- Header: `content-type: application/json;odata=verbose`
- Body variations I've tried:

```
{
    '__metadata':
        {'type':'SP.Field'}, 
        'Title': 'Test Field1',
        'FieldTypeKind': 3,

        'Title': 'Test Field2',
        'FieldTypeKind': 3
}
```

```
[
    '__metadata':
        {'type':'SP.Field'}, 
        'Title': 'Test Field1',
        'FieldTypeKind': 3,

    '__metadata':
        'Title': 'Test Field2',
        'FieldTypeKind': 3
]
```

```
[{
    '__metadata':
        {'type':'SP.Field'}, 
        'Title': 'Test Field1',
        'FieldTypeKind': 3,

    '__metadata':
        'Title': 'Test Field2',
        'FieldTypeKind': 3
]}
```

```
{
    '__metadata':
        {'type':'SP.Field'}, 
        'Title': 'Test Field1',
        'FieldTypeKind': 3
},
{

    '__metadata':
        'Title': 'Test Field2',
        'FieldTypeKind': 3
}
```

```
{
    '__metadata':[
        {'type':'SP.Field'}, 
        'Title': 'Test Field1',
        'FieldTypeKind': 3,
        {'type':'SP.Field'},
        'Title': 'Test Field2',
        'FieldTypeKind': 3
    ]
}
```

etc... All error out in various ways. There's gotta be a way to do this! Any insights?

Comment: The JSON you're trying to pass is in the incorrect format. But what is the question though?

Comment: What is the correct POST Body (JSON format) for creating multiple fields (columns) in a single HTTP call?

Comment: Hello @ericOnline, hope you are doing well. Just checking were you able to find any solution for your question?

Answer (score 0):

Going back through my notes... I used PowerAutomate to perform this action. I ended up creating a FOR EACH loop on the array of columns to create.

**Here is what worked:**

**Uri**:

- `_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('varListName')}')/Fields`

**Headers**:

- `content-type:` "application/json;odata=verbose"`
- `accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"`

**Body**:

```
{
    'Title': 'varFieldName',
    'FieldTypeKind': varFieldType
}
```

I hope this helps you.